# (cordova) (inappbrowser) Let users know that you're getting their page ready

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, inappbrowser

I've an app built with cordova and InAppBrowser. I'm trying to show a "loading spinner " or a "loading message" (instead of having a blank page while the inappbrowser is loading) , I tried to do it but it's not working , here is my app.js code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

var ref;

function onDeviceReady() {  
      
      try {    
    ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://cordova.apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', loadStartCallBack);
    ref.addEventListener("exit", onBackButton, false); 
   }
   catch(err) {
    alert("Plugin Error - " + err.message);
   }
   
   

  function onBackButton(e) {
   navigator.app.exitApp();
  }

  function loadStartCallBack() {

    $('#status-message').text("loading please wait ...");

}
}
```

And here is my index.html code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" >
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <title>InApp Browser</title>
       
    </head>
    <body>      
   <script type="text/javascript">
        navigator.splashscreen.show();
        </script>
  <div id="status-message"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It didn't show result in browser please make the build then test in your mobile device or just test it in emulator .

Comment: I already made the build and tested it in emulator , but it didn't show result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [loadstop callback](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#inappbrowseraddeventlistener) should do the trick for you.

Remember to add the property **hidden=yes** as third parameter in the `browser.open` method, otherwise the browser will be always visible and you won't see the loading message :

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://cordova.apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=yes');
```

Finally your code should look like :

```
<script>
var ref;

function onDeviceReady() {
    try {
        ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://cordova.apache.org', '_blank', 'location=no,hidden=yes');
        ref.addEventListener('loadstart', loadStartCallBack);
        ref.addEventListener("loadstop", loadEndCallback, false);
        ref.addEventListener("exit", onBackButton, false);
    } catch (err) {
        alert("Plugin Error - " + err.message);
    }

    function onBackButton(e) {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }

    function loadStartCallBack() {
        $('#status-message').text("loading please wait ...");
    }

    function loadEndCallback(){
        alert("Your page has been loaded, showing ...");
        $('#status-message').text("");
        ref.show();
    }
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>
```

Do you get another specific error or something with the remote debbuging in chrome?

Comment: No , the `<div id="status-message"></div>` is in my index.html , so when the inappbrowser is loading the index.html is hiden , so what to do ????

Comment: :facepalm: i didn't saw neither. See my fix, you need to add the hidden=yes property to the InAppBrowser.open @Imen.A

Comment: @CarlosDelgado I don't want to have the  alert box , I just want to see "Loading please wait.." , so i edited **loadEndCallback function** like this : `function loadEndCallback(){
       // alert("Your page has been loaded, showing ...");
       // $('#status-message').text("");
        ref.show();
    }` is it a good modification or not  ???

Comment: @Imen.A yeah sure, it's your project :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't show loading message, because if you open Inappbrowser, your app goes to background so, the div `<div id="status-message"></div>` will be hide.

```
 var Ref;
   Ref = window.open('http://www.example.com', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
             Ref.addEventListener('loadstart', inAppBrowserbLoadStart);
             Ref.addEventListener('loadstop', inAppBrowserbLoadStop);
             Ref.addEventListener('loaderror', inAppBrowserbLoadError);
             Ref.addEventListener('exit', inAppBrowserbClose);


       function inAppBrowserbLoadStart(event) {

             navigator.notification.activityStart("Please Wait", "Its loading....");
             alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);

        }

        function inAppBrowserbLoadStop(event) {
             navigator.notification.activityStop();
             alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);

        }

        function inAppBrowserbLoadError(event) {
             navigator.notification.activityStop();
             alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.message);
        }

        function inAppBrowserbClose(event) {

             Ref.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
             Ref.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
             Ref.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
             Ref.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
        }
```

Comment: so what I have to do ??